# How to connect to localhost with postgres_fdw?

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, pgadmin, foreign-data-wrapper

The idea is that I have local database named `northwind`, and with `postgres_fdw` I want to connect with another database named `test` on localhost (remote connection simulation, for situations like when table in my database is updated, do something in other database like save to history etc..). So I opened psql console and type:

```
CREATE SERVER app_db 
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw 
OPTIONS (dbname 'test', host 'localhost:5432');
```

As i found in [A Look at Foreign Data Wrappers](http://www.craigkerstiens.com/2013/08/05/a-look-at-FDWs/) link. Next I also follow the tutorial:

```
CREATE USER MAPPING for postgres
SERVER app_db 
OPTIONS (user 'postgres', password 'postgres');
```

(I assume that user and password should be the same as I used e.g. in Hibernate to access database, and in place `current_user` from tutorial is `postgres` in my case cause this is the only role which exists in my PgAdmin III).
Then I created foreign table:

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE groups
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  name character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  version integer DEFAULT 0
)
 SERVER app_db OPTIONS (table_name 'groups')
```

And that's ok I can find it in `schema/foreign tables` in PgAdmin III. But when I try to `SELECT * FROM groups` I got:

```
********** ERROR**********

ERROR: could not connect to server "app_db"
SQL State: 08001
```

Is it possible because when I `CREATE SERVER app_db..` I don't use localhost server name? I can't because it has name with space (PostgreSQL 9.3) and it causes some weird problems while creating. Thank you in advance.
**Update**: It doesn't work even if I create another server named`app_db on localhost.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After many attempts probably I found a proper way to connect:

```
CREATE SERVER app_db 
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw 
OPTIONS (dbname 'test', port '5432', host 'localhost');
```

Then:

```
CREATE USER MAPPING for postgres
SERVER app_db 
OPTIONS (user 'postgres', password 'postgres');
```

And then:

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE groups
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  name character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  version integer DEFAULT 0
)
 SERVER app_db OPTIONS (schema_name 'public', table_name 'groups')
```

But is there a solution to check if it's really "remote" connection? Because servers are on the same localhost and I don't know if I can be sure.

Comment: Sorry for asking here, but i follow step by step your advices and i get this error when i perform a select `ERROR:  could not connect to server "omnes_db"
DETAIL:  could not connect to server: Connection refused
 Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5431?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
 Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5431?` the `pg_hba.cong` and `postgresql.conf` files are setup properly for allowing remove secured connections.REally don't know what to do

Comment: Update: The above answer works perfectly for my case https://stackoverflow.com/a/39259965/903998. For  accessing another database located within hthe same instance of postgres, you can ommit the host and port for the server and also the password for the user mapping. Probably you must allow access to the foreign table by granting at least "select" permissions.

Answer (score 12):

You may connect using Unix Domain Socket instead of TCP connection to gain simpler configuration and better performance (Linux/Unix only, not supported in Windows).

```
CREATE SERVER app_db
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
OPTIONS (dbname 'test');
```

Also, you may omit the password if `peer` authentication is enabled (default).

```
CREATE USER MAPPING for postgres
SERVER app_db 
OPTIONS (user 'postgres');
```

Note:
`peer` authentication can only be used for `postgres` user as the FDW connection is created by the server backend which runs as the system user `postgres`.

Also, for security reasons, postgresq_fdw allows `peer` authentication only for clients with `SUPERUSER` privilege. To allow restricted users to use the FDW, you have to use `password` authentication as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29901740/1332370)