# How to query two postgres databases (with a single query) when the databases are within the same postgres server?

Tags: postgresql

For example, assuming that table `A` is in database `example` and table `B` is in database `postgres`, how to perform the following query on the two tables?:

```
SELECT
 A.date,
 A.name,
 B.date,
 B.name
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.name = B.name;
```

[image]

Comment: Your previous answer was correct, the linked question is about two databases which are located on different postgres servers, whereas your answer was for two databases in the same postgres server

Comment: Yes syntax correct but it cannot produce because `foreign key` cannot connect to other database.. `Postgresql` cannot do Query joining on `Across Database`..

Comment: @Greg: it doesn't matter if the database are on the same server or different servers. In both cases you would use a foreign data wrapper: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36904631

Comment: allow me to add useful references for any reader: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678862/joining-results-from-two-separate-databases and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29900748/how-to-connect-to-localhost-with-postgres-fdw